# How to export dynamically create Primefaces bar charts

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have managed to create Primefaces barcharts dynamically using xhtml code below:

```
<p:dataGrid id="chartdataGrid" var="controlLoopChart" value="#{analysisreports.controlLoopCharts}"  columns="1" style="border:none;">
      <p:chart type="bar" model="#{controlLoopChart.bcharts}"/>
</p:dataGrid>
```

My Question is how to export these dynamically generated bar charts to image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty easy using `JavaScript` in `PrimeFaces` you can save it as a image.
Following code will help you: while `chart` is `widgetVar` for targeted chart

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="exportChart()"/>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" modal="true" header="Chart as an Image" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="output" layout="block" style="width:500px;height:300px"/>
</p:dialog>

<script type="text/javascript">
function exportChart() {
    //export image
    $('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());

    //show the dialog
    PF('dlg').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i know that way but what about the dynamic bar chart which are generated based on database ?

Comment: Chart converts to image when ever you call this JS function. If you manage to create/show bar chart based on database. it will give chart currently loaded on web page

Comment: chart exports to image based on chart id, how to give different ids based on number of charts to export it as image ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? are you asking about the file name of image? if yes, you can change it before saving it. As it shows dialog than you save it manually by right clicking on it.

Comment: Your answer is true in case of a single chart. but my problem is i'm generating multiple charts based on data available in databse. So the number of charts isn't fix. And i don't know how to give uniques ID's to export them as image plus i don't know how many charts are going to be there as it's dynamic thing

Comment: Do you have dynamic `<p:chart />` component in `xhtml` based on data? or you just rendering it?

Comment: so i have a list of bar charts in bean which i'm showing using datagrid and in it i'm showing charts.